# toilet flush problems

Tags: bathroom

I used plunger,chemicles,snake, several times upto 8 ft, replaced entire filler assembly.Flapjack won't matter cause i've held it up to get a complete flush and it didn't make a difference. the bowl is filling up but it onle glugs,instead of PATUUSH! Help please

Comment: Have you checked/snaked your vents? Is it only 1 toilet, or multiple? Sewer systems or septic tank?

Comment: At the front of the bowl, there's usually a hole just under the water where the jet comes out.  Get your finger in there and make sure it's not restricted.

Answer (score 4):

That means you either have a clog farther down the line than an 8' snake can reach, or you have a blocked vent. You can try snaking your vent. You can also try running a garden hose down the vent, but you run the risk of overflowing the drains in your house so be careful. Otherwise, you'll need to rent a longer snake or pay a plumber to come out and fix it for you.

Comment: Would it also be possible that the toilet is not properly sealed to the pipe? Or that doesn't matter at all?